# Angular 6 http.get subscribe getting the same data without querying api

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular6

I am trying to do a search query using my node api from angular. I am subscribing to the api call http get request and am getting the correct data back the first time. In the second request after updating the params it returns the same data in the subscription and the call is never received on the API end? How do I get the subscribe to show my new data and make the updated api call? I am using angular 6.0.9 and rxjs 6.2.2

**api.ts**

```
@Injectable()
export class API {
  public apiBase = '';
  headers = new HttpHeaders();
  options: any;

  constructor(public http: HttpClient) {
    this.apiBase = environment.api;
    this.headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    this.options = {
      headers: this.headers
    };
  }

  searchProperties(data: any): Observable<any> {
    let params = {}
    for(var d in data) {
      params[d] = JSON.stringify(data[d]);
    }
    return this.http.get(this.apiBase + '/properties/search', {params: params})
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }
```

}

**search.component.ts**

```
ngOnInit() {
  // works fine here with new data
  this.searchQuery();
}

searchQuery() {
  this.api.searchProperties(this.searchData)
    .map(result => {
        console.log('map: ', result);
        }
    })
    .subscribe(res => {
        console.log(res);
    });
}

searchAgain(lat, lng) {
  // calls the query and gets all the way to the api call and returns the same data as the previous call without hitting the api at all.
  this.searchData.lat = lat;
  this.searchData.lng = lng;
  this.searchQuery();
}
```

Comment: Well, you must call searchProperties() and subscribe() again. Why do you think that changing the lat and lng of searchData should send a new request? Note that your headers are useless : you append a content type, but ignore the returned HttpHeaders, thus leaving the headers empty. And setting the content-type of a GET request doesn't make sense anyway, since get requests don't have a content. Sending JSON values as request parameters, is really ugly, too.

Comment: @JBNizet Sorry, my mistake. I left that call out when copying over. It was in there. I have just updated it

Comment: And with the headers I don't pass them to the get requests, I have more post requests where I pass them but I am just showing the skeleton of my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case it'd be more clear and convenient to use rxjs' `Subject` for emitting new search parameters on demand and to mix that http call in into this pipeline using something like `switchMap()` or `flatMap()`. Also, this way you'll not have to manage multiple subscription attempts manually - which, btw, ideally you should be doing but you're not doing it. There will be only one subscription that is made when it all starts. I'd suggest something like the code below.

One more thing to do is to check your browser console for any errors related to your code. It looks like there should be something else preventing it from going through. I've written tons of such code and it always worked normally. So, if this suggestion won't work then this means that you have something else outside of the code you provided that makes this thing to misbehave... but it's highly unlikely that anyone will be able to guess where the problem is - unless you provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). And I think that in this pretty simple case you'll be able to solve your problem just by trying to prepare such an example.

```
private searchParams = new Subject();

ngOnInit() {
  // works fine here with new data
  this.searchQuery();
}

searchQuery() {
    this.searchParams.pipe(
        startWith(<whatever_default_search_params_are>),
        switchMap(params => this.api.searchProperties(params))
    ).subscribe(res => {
        console.log(res);
    });
}

searchAgain(lat, lng) {
  this.searchParams.next({lat: lat, lng: lng});
}
```

Comment: Cheers for the help. A definitely cleaner way to go rather than another subscribing. I was having the same problem still though. Does http have a default cache as I added a random timestamp to the query and it started working?

Comment: No, I pretty much use chrome solely unless cross browser debugging. It seems to be caching within http.get as watching the network tab the request to the sever is never made the second time unless the timestamp is included. The search params are made up of a larger object I haven't shown which generally stays the same unless the filters are updated but the bounds (lat,lng) and the search text are updated in the object.